# Evans PDE page 250. Smooth functions are dense in Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

On page 250 Evans' PDE book proves that smooth functions are dense in the space of weak derivatives.

One step that confuses me is

$$D^\alpha u^\epsilon(x) = \int_U D^\alpha_x \eta_\epsilon(x-y)u(y) dy = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \int_U D^\alpha_y \eta_\epsilon(x-y)u(y) dy $$

Here $\eta_\epsilon$ is the standard mollifier and $u^\epsilon$ is the convolution of $\eta_\epsilon$ and $u.$

I do not understand how he switched the derivative from $x$ to $y$. If it is $x \to -y$, why is the integral still with respect to $dy$? this is a multi-index derivative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the one-dimensional case with $\alpha=1$.
Then we have
$$
D_x \eta_\varepsilon(x-y).
= \eta_\varepsilon'(x-y)
= -D_y \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)
$$
The multi-dimensional case is similar, but the factor is not $-1$ but $(-1)^{|\alpha|}$ because you have to do the same trick $|\alpha|$ times.

**A 2-dimensional example**:
Next, consider the two-dimensional case with $\alpha=(1,1)$.

We have to be careful to not confuse the derivatives with respect to
a variable (like $\tfrac{d}{dx_1}$) with partial derivatives of functions.
For the function $\eta_\varepsilon:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ we will denote
its partial derivatives by $\partial_1$ and $\partial_2$.

We have
$$
D_x^\alpha\eta_\varepsilon(x-y)
= \tfrac{d}{dx_1}\tfrac{d}{dx_2} \eta_\varepsilon(x-y)
= \partial_1\partial_2\eta_\varepsilon(x-y)
\\\qquad\qquad= \partial_1(-\tfrac{d}{dy_2}\eta_\varepsilon(x-y))
= -\tfrac{d}{dy_1}(-\tfrac{d}{dy_2}\eta_\varepsilon(x-y))
= (-1)^2 D_y^\alpha\eta_\varepsilon(x-y).
$$

Comment: I know it works when it is one variable, but in the multi dimensional case, we have $\eta( (x_1-y_1, x_2 - y_2))$, so do you have to test it on $\partial_{y_1}$, $\partial_{x_2}$ for example? This is when $\alpha = 2$. Can you just show me one example of a multi-dim case?

Comment: @Hawk It is not clear to me which example you are looking for. If you want something $n$-dimensional, then $\alpha$ should also be $n$-dimensional, for example, $\alpha=(1,1)$.

Comment: I meant $|\alpha| = 2$, but yes for example, $(1,1)$ are we computing for example, $\partial_{y_1}\partial_{x_2}\eta(x_1 - y_1,x_2-y_2)$ i m just a little confused with what $x $ and $y$ were in $D^\alpha_x$ and $D^\alpha_y$

Comment: Okay so I was right, $\partial_{x_2}\eta(x_1 - y_1,x_2 - y_2) = -\partial_{y_2}\eta(x_1 - y_1,x_2 - y_2)$